# 1 item, many configuration options

Tags: magento, import, magmi, magento-1.8, configurable-product

Example item

```
___________________________________________________
| ITEM  | COLOR | SIZE | QTY |  PRICE |    SKU    |
===================================================
| Shirt | Black |    S |  35 |  $8.00 | ShirtBS   |
| Shirt | Black |    M |  52 |  $8.00 | ShirtBM   |
| Shirt | Black |    L |  19 |  $8.00 | ShirtBL   |
| Shirt | Black |   XL |  27 |  $8.00 | ShirtBXL  |
| Shirt | Black |  XXL |  16 | $10.00 | ShirtBXXL |
| Shirt | White |    S |  17 |  $8.00 | ShirtWS   |
| Shirt | White |    M |  20 |  $8.00 | ShirtWM   |
| Shirt | White |  XXL |   9 | $10.00 | ShirtWXXL |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I have my items set up as

```
Item 1 - $8 - Qty 16
 Shirt (Black)
  - select box (size) - options S|M|L|XL|XXL (+$2) { SKU starting ShirtB- }
Item 2 - $8 - Qty 9
 Shirt (White)
  - select box (size) - options S|M|XXL (+$2) { SKU starting ShirtW- }
```

Is there a configuration where my customer can view it as 1 item, where they select color and size options will change based on color they choose, and SKU will follow with proper selection?

Even better if quantities follow through, currently I am setting base quantity on whatever the lowest number is (so `Shirt (White)` lists 9 available and `Shirt (Black)` lists 16; using my example above)

```
Item - $8
 - select box (color) - options Black|White
 + selected 'Black'
  - select box (size) - options S|M|L|XL|XXL (+$2) {SKU starting ShirtB- }
 + selected 'White'
  - select box (size) - options S|M|XXL (+$2) { SKU starting ShirtW- }
```

I am willing to accept paid add-on's through Magento store if necessary (and not prohibitive in cost), although I would hope that this functionality is built in and I am just not able to find it

My import is through MAGMI, so special bonus points if it can be easily accomplished this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is typically handled by a standard "configurable product" in magento.

see [this tutorial](https://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product)

Magmi is able to process configurable products through its "configurable" plugin.

Depending on the pricing model that suits you the most , you may also try "[Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html)" extension.